# Bower cannot find a package and fails to install new packages

Tags: bower, bower-install

So I installed via `bower` - `jQuery UI Sortable`. The package's folder was put right in my assets folder as expected. Then I wanted to install another package (for example: `noty.js` with `bower install --save noty`) and I get this:

```
bower noty#*                not-cached https://github.com/needim/noty.git#*
bower noty#*                   resolve https://github.com/needim/noty.git#*
bower fullcalendar#*            cached https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.git#3.4.0
bower fullcalendar#*          validate 3.4.0 against https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.git#*
bower noty#*                  download https://github.com/needim/noty/archive/v3.1.1.tar.gz
bower noty#*                   extract archive.tar.gz
bower noty#*                  resolved https://github.com/needim/noty.git#3.1.1
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package jQuery UI Sortable=jquery-ui-sortable not found
```

***Note***: I tried installing fullcalendar as well.

Even though it says it downloaded the package and extracted `archive.tar.gz`, that package is nowhere to be found in my project's folder. `jQuery UI Sortable` is still there. I'm even using it.

`bower.json` is left untouched. If I run `bower install --save noty` it just says:

```
bower noty#*                    cached https://github.com/needim/noty.git#3.1.1
bower noty#*                  validate 3.1.1 against https://github.com/needim/noty.git#*
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package jQuery UI Sortable=jquery-ui-sortable not found
```

I have a `.bowerrc` that points to `resources/assets/bower` (because it's a Laravel project). So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error is because bower uses the `name` to build the directory structure and define the actual name of the package. jQuery UI Sortable package defines the name using uppercase letters and spaces inside `bower.json` file like this:

```
{
  "name": "jQuery UI Sortable",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
```

which obviously is not a so good idea, to have uppercase letters and spaces to a package directory name:

[image: jQuery UI Sortable]

So, we need to change the name from `jQuery UI Sortable` to `jquery-ui-sortable` and get rid of the spaces and uppercase letters. To do this, we have to define the name by using `<package_installed_name>=<package_list_name>`, which in our case will be:

```
bower install --save jquery-ui-sortable=jquery-ui-sortable
```

After you do this, just install `noty` and it should successfully install it:

```
bower install noty
```

[image: Bower Noty install]

[image: jQuery UI Sortable and Noty together]

Don't forget to delete the `jQuery UI Sortable` directory inside bower packages directory before you try to install `jquery-ui-sortable` with the proper name.